# How to order TestMethods of execution using Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, testing

I am writing test cases using using VS 2010

I have list of test methods and i am looking to run test cases in a particular order
for an example, here is i have few test methods.

```
[TestMethod]
public void AddEmployee()
{
   //
}

[TestMethod]
public void UpdateEmployee()
{
   //
}

[TestMethod]
public void DeleteEmployee()
{
   //
}
```

Comment: Although chrismead's answer is fully valid, if you need to have unit tests in a specific order, this *might* be a hint of a design flaw. Unit Tests should be independent from each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an 'Ordered Test' :

[How to: Create an Ordered Test](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182631.aspx)

The tests end up listed in an XML file that Visual Studio executes.